# RollingFileAppender - rolling yearly?

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

Is it possible to set the RollingFileAppender to roll yearly rather than monthly? There won't be enough entries to require one file per month, so I'd like to set it up on a yearly basis, but when I set the `datePattern = "yyyy"` log4net said it was unable to parse (Invalid Roll Point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

RollingFileAppender.RollPoint.TopOfMonth is the biggest value.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollPoint.html for reference.

Comment: Thank you. This would be a nice feature to have. My app needs to keep a log of when something occurred, but it's not frequent enough for a monthly log. I've changed it to roll by size and made the size large enough that it should use the same file for quite a while before requiring a roll.